# Easiest API to learn/methdology to create web applications for running mapreduce on hadoop?

Tags: api, web-applications, hadoop, mapreduce

I have hadoop 1.0.4 running on my ubuntu 11.04,configured with eclipse I want to make a web application to run hadoop jobs, or may be Cassandra,Hbase and Hive might be a way but I don't have much time to learn thoroughly all these and I want to do it as quickly as possible.Any advice which one might prove the easiest to get started with ?

Comment: Easiest way to start with would be to go through a good web services tutorial.

Comment: @Tariq any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this question really qualifies to be here on SO in its current form. This is the reason I did not write this initially. But, a lot of SO experts are out there to decide this(they can do it much better than me) :)

Having said that, I would like to share a few things with you based on my personal experience, so that you proceed towards the correct path. First of all, Hadoop jobs(MapReduce) and Hive are actually not a good fit for web services kinda use cases. They are most suitable for **offline, batch processing** kinda stuff. HBase/Cassandra can be used though, if you have **real time needs**(like web services).

Coming back to your actual question. Before diving into Hadoop, Hive, HBase etc, I would suggest you to get some hold on web services first(if you are new to web services as well). Reason being, a web service is something which has much wider scope of applicability as compared to tools like Hadoop, Hive, HBase etc. These tools are specific to some particular use cases and cannot be used everywhere. But, web services are used almost everywhere and with **n** number of different things, like RDBMSs, NoSQL datastores etc etc. So if you know web service concepts you definitely have that extra edge. To begin with you can visit these links :

- [Web Services Tutorial by W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp)(Nice n easy. Would serve the quick start guide purpose).
- For a detailed tutorial you can visit the [oracle web services tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijqy.html).
- This [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-top10/) by IBM developerworks has references to some really good web services learning stuff.
- You might find [this one](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/TopDownAxis2WebService/td_tutorial.html) really helpful to start with(Shows how to create web services using Eclipse).
- And you can obviously Google **web service tutorials** anytime.

One last thing. Although it's not mandatory to be a **pro** in things like Hadoop, Hive, HBase etc, but having some decent amount of understanding of the concepts would be really helpful in developing your solution in a much better manner. It'll allow you to think accurately in the correct direction.

HTH.

Comment: sorry for bumping like this one year later, but I really liked your answer, so I had to ask you this - how would you realize a system that has a need for something such as a web service, and in the same time it needs Hadoop implementation, concretely Mahout clustering, that is done periodically for the whole data,but also for each data that arrives it is determined to which cluster it belongs,based on current clusters.The data comes continually,my idea was through a web service,that then feds data to Mahout.How would you realize something like this?Thank you very much,in advance.